# 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'load' when using Image.putalpha()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

code:

```
    avatar = Image.open('temp_avatar.png').convert('RGBA')
    color = (255,255,255,0)
    mask = Image.new("L", avatar.size, 0)
    mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)

    size = avatar.width
    mask_draw.polygon([~irrelevant~], fill=255)

    avatar_finale = avatar.copy()
    avatar_finale.putalpha(mask_draw)
    avatar_finale.save('temp_avatar.png')
```

error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\amit2\source\repos\LAKRIS bot\LAKRIS bot\cogs\rank.py", line 42, in processing
avatar_finale.putalpha(mask_draw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1654, in putalpha
    alpha.load()
AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'load'
```

i dont really know what the problem is, i ran a very similar code with .putalpha() and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your penultimate line is wrong - it is trying to put the Draw object of the mask, rather than mask itself, itself into the alpha channel.

So, replace:

```
avatar_finale.putalpha(mask_draw)
```

with:

```
avatar_finale.putalpha(mask)
```

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project and remember to come back if you get stuck. Questions (and answers) are free.